# Is this an okay way to reverse a string without any temporary variables?

Tags: c++

I was wondering whether the C++ purists could give me some input. Critique my approach and my adherence to proper coding form. Let me know about any red flags that tell you I'm an amateur.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void rev_string(std::string& s) 
{ 
    unsigned len = s.length();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < len / 2; ++i)
    {
        s[i]           = (char)((int)s[i] + (int)s[len - i - 1]);
        s[len - i - 1] = (char)((int)s[i] - (int)s[len - i - 1]);
        s[i]           = (char)((int)s[i] - (int)s[len - i - 1]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::string myString = "Obama was born in Kenya.";

    rev_string(myString);
    std::cout << myString;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use `std::reverse`.

Comment: @chris , that's not as "cool", though

Comment: Even without `std::reverse`, the answer is no, that is not an okay way to reverse a string.  In particular, the swapping.  Just use a temporary variable, anything else is stupid.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with all the casts, adds, subtractions, etc.

Comment: @MarshallMathers clear code >>>>>>> "cool" code.

Comment: I would still count `i` as a temporary variable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for  improving working code stylistically. It appears to be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Plenty of things tell me you're an amateur. Writing silly code like this is a dead giveaway. The weird cast tricks you're playing that can break horribly. Using `unsigned` to store the return of `std::string::length()`. Etc.

Comment: What's wrong with temporaries?

Answer (score 2):

To codify `chris`' comment above, I would write this:

```
#include <algorithm>

void rev_string(std::string& s) { 
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

Comment: +1 I would just write whats *in* this function and throw out the function entirely.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

1. Don't prematurely optimise. Don't be afraid to use variables no matter how little they are used. Many modern compilers will be able to recognise when and where (and sometimes how) they are used and in many cases variables are "optimised out".
2. Signed integer types do not wrap around (or rather, they are not guaranteed to “wrap” as unsigned types do). The underlying architecture may support wrapping of signed integer types and so it may appear to work, but GCC is known to optimise based on the assumption that signed types don't wrap (see [here](http://thiemonagel.de/2010/01/signed-integer-overflow/)).
3. If you are using C++, you should just use the built-in [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: Nice answer, but link from point 2. leads to some text in German.

Comment: @SChepurin: Whoops, had an erroneous character in the URL. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three options right now (from most to least desirable):

1. Use `std::reverse`
2. If you refuse to use `std::reverse`, you can define your own `reverse` that uses `std::swap`.
3. If you refuse to use `std::swap`, you can define your own. But *please* have mercy and use a `temp`. Don't make it harder to read your code!

---

Here's are some examples:

`std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());`

OR

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) {

    int size = str.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) 
        std::swap(str[i], str[size-i-1]);

    return str;

}
```

OR If you refuse to use `std::swap`

```
void swap(std::string& str, int index1, int index2) {

    char temp = str[index1];
    str[index1] = str[index2];
    str[index2] = temp;

}

std::string reverse(std::string str) {

    int size = str.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) 
        swap (str, i, size - i - 1);

    return str;

}
```